# Please I would like to understand this code better

Tags: python, performance

```
import sys
import time
command=""
started=False
while True:
    name=input("Enter your name! ")
    if name!="":
        break
if len(name)<3:
    print("name's too short ")
    time.sleep(1)
    exit()
answer=input(f"Hello {name} do you want to play my game! ").lower()
if answer== "yes":
    while command!=("quit"):
        command=input("press 's' to start, p to pause or q to quit ").lower()
        if command==("s"):
            if started:
                print('car already started')
            else:
                started=True
                print("car started")
        elif command==("p"):
            if not started:
                print('car already stopped')
            else:
                started=False
                print("car stopped")
                
        elif command==("q"):
                        print("game ended")
                        time.sleep(2)
                        exit()
        else:
            print(" i dont understand")
```

[image]

When I run this code and I press 's' to start I get 'car started' and when I tried pressing 's' again I get car already started but I got confused at "started=True
Print("car started")". I was wondering since started is set to True shouldn't the print statement be ("car already started")
although the program is working good but when looking at the code I am just a bit confused and please I would need a bit clarification on the code.

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is only for questions about [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news), but not for a game written in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are confused about the `started = True` part, I will try and focus on that mainly.

What the `if started` condition does is checks if you have already typed `s` beforehand. If you have, i.e. `if started`, then `print('car already started')` runs.

You may be confused about the `if` statement not having a condition, i.e. `if started`. This is just a shorthand for writing `if started == True`, as an if statement evaluates the condition based on `True` or `False`.

Once the user has typed `s` and hasn't typed `s` before, the boolean `started` is set to `True` (previously False) and `print("car started")` runs. This ensures that the next time you type `s`, the `if` statement runs again, and since `if started` is true, `print('car already started')` runs.

The `if not` statement checks the opposite, i.e. `if not started` means the same thing as `if started == False`.